# Generating averages and standard deviations for same time range over many days

Tags: promql

I would like to write some alerts to recognize anomalies in system performance. I have some counter metrics for errors, which vary during the day in proportion to the number of active users.

My goal is to use the hourly average and standard deviation to flag unusual error levels. I have two week's worth of data and, for instance, if the current time was 11:00 am , I would like to compare every 10:00 to 11:00 am time window on each of the days for which I have data.

I would like something like this (I know that this is not legitimate PromQl):

```yaml
groups:
  - name: my_alert_rules
    rules:
    - record: average_1h_error_rate
      expr: average(
         sum(rate(error_count{some_label="some_value"}[1h])) offset 1d
         + sum(rate(error_count{some_label="some_value"}[1h])) offset 2d
         ...
         + sum(rate(error_count{some_label="some_value"}[1h])) offset 10d
      )
```

And then do a similar thing for the standard deviation. I can then use these two values to spot the anomalies, I hope.

I've searched, and can't find a good example of how to do this kind of thing, or even if such a thing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus does support the offset modifier, you've just got it in the wrong place. And you don't need an average function, just divide by the number of days you've added up. Try this:

```
(sum(rate(error_count{some_label="some_value"}[1h] offset 1d))
 + sum(rate(error_count{some_label="some_value"}[1h] offset 2d))
 ...
 + sum(rate(error_count{some_label="some_value"}[1h] offset 10d))
) / 10
```